# Database Schema for Related Object Types

Tags: sql, database, database-design, data-structures, schema

Brief background - working on a site for a non-profit where they can post 3 things:

1. Status updates
2. Needs
3. Events

Each of those post types can have 1 or more tags, e.g. homelessness, hunger awareness, etc.

My question is how I should design the schema to best handle this. Here a pseudo-schema of what I'm thinking so far:

### Org_Post Table

- id, PK
- user_id, FK (who posted this?)
- post_type_id, FK  (what type of post is this? status, need or event)
- post_object_id, FK (id could come from one of 3 tables, post_status, post_need, post_event)

### Org_Post_Tags table

- id, PK
- org_post_id, FK (which post is this tag associated with)
- tag_id, FK (which tag)

### Post_Status table

- id, PK
- status

### Post_Need table

- id, PK
- need_title
- need_date
- need_quantity
- need_details

### Post_Event table

- id, PK
- event_start_date
- event_start_time
- event_end_date
- event_end_time
- event_location
- event_details
- event_title

Am I over-complicating this? Am I missing something that will make querying for this data a nightmare?

As always, thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There's one issue I see with this - You can't put a foreign key on `Org_Post.post_object_id` as this field may reference any one of 3 tables.

Other than that, your design looks like the fairly standard approach.

**For the above issue, I suggest the following:**

Org_Post Table

- id, PK
- user_id, FK

Org_Post_Tags table

- ...

Post_Status table

- id, PK
- ...
- **ord_post_id, FK**

Post_Need table

- id, PK
- ...
- **ord_post_id, FK**

Post_Event table

- id, PK
- ...
- **ord_post_id, FK**